# Correctly calling variables inside a function

Tags: python

As an example

```
def Test():
    Function = 'one'

print(Function)
```

How does one go about doing that?
At the moment I get

NameError: name 'Function' is not defined

Comment: It should be "NameError: name 'Function' is not defined"

Comment: "How does one go about doing that?" - doing what exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that. `Function` is only defined inside the `Test()` method.

If you want to, you should make the method return the string as follows:

```
def Test():
    Function = 'one'
    return Function

a = Test()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

The variable is out of the scope of that function. Either call that function or in the worst case you can use `global` keyword too.

Way 1 (better option):

```
def Test():
    Function = 'one'
    return Function

#If you print Function now, you will get the name error!
print(Function)

>>> NameError: name 'Function' is not defined
# If you call the function that works!!

print (Test())
>>> one
```

Way 2 (worse one):

```
>>> Function=''
>>> def Test():
        global Function
        Function = 'one'


>>> print(Test())
None
>>> print(Function)
one
>>>
```